Почему не работает \n при интерполяции?
почему такой код не работает? Почему не переносится строка?
console.log(`First: ${text[length(text) - 56]}` \n`Last: ${text[length(text) - 1]}`);


\n не туда завернул

исправил все равно не работает(

@RuddyLumber сомневаюсь, что исправил, если все еще не работает. Покажи код.

У вас в коде есть несколько синтаксический ошибок, вы используете length как функцию (length - это свойство), так же вы исправили /n на \n, но добавили кавычки, и пробелы \n должен быть частью строки, заключенной в шаблонные строки (``). Вы не можете использовать \n вне строковых литералов


const text = "ABCD-1234-EFGH-5678-IJKL-9012-MNOP-3456-QRST-7890-CORP-V";
console.log(`First: ${text[text.length - 56]}\nLast: ${text[text.length - 1]}`);




Что делает ваш код: он берет длину строки, отнимает 56
и выводит символ на 0-й позиции, поскольку длина строки теперь составляет 56 символов, то символ на позиции text.length - 56 будет первым символом строки.
Затем он берет длину строки, отнимает 1 и выводит последний символ строки.
Все это мы выводим в столбик, но в данном случае First является первым символом строки,
поскольку длина строки равна 56. Однако, если бы строка длиннее, First не обязательно первый символ.
